# Has anybody ever managed to upload the Mac OS X app to the new iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode6

What I did.

1. Using Xcode 6 I created a new project File > New project > Cocoa Application
2. At the developer portal http://developer.apple.com I created a new App ID, Development and Distribution Profiles.
3. Input Bundle identifier and added provision profiles and signing identity to the project.
4. Added all icons for all sizes in images.xcassets.
5. Added App Sandbox entitlement and app category to the project.
6. Everything else I left by default.
7. Tried to Archive and Validate. Got the following error:

[image]

Weird because it's not an iOS app at all. And I have the distribution provision (for Mac OS X app) profile attached.

Okay, I uploaded the .pkg with Application Loader.

**The question**: why I don't see the icon of the app?

[image]

What does that yellow question mark mean?
It seems I can't add the icon any other way:

[image]

No Add, Edit or Upload button.

Can anybody tell me please is it only my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/distribution/itc I realised that I have to submit the app to review to see the icon. And indeed after that the icon appeared... Ufff....

The problem with validation is common at the moment. You can submit the app without validation. It works.